# react-create-app using font-awesome

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and I'm trying to integrate font-awesome so I can use it in my SPA.

I've done `npm install font-awesome` and it's installed, but when I try to call `import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'` I get the following error:

```
Compiling...
Failed to compile.

Error in ./~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
Module parse failed: C:\Projects\myproject\ui\node_modules\font-awesome\css\font-awesome.css Unexpected character '@' (7:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@' (7:0)
 @ ./src/index.js 11:0-44
```

Comment: In which file you have added the import statement? When I tried it on App.js file, it works for me. My App.js looks something as similar as 

`import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'`

Comment: Edit: It also works when I import it on `index.js` instead of `App.js`, After the import my index.js looks like something as similar as `import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'`

Comment: @GaleelBhasha very weird.  I completely purged my `node_modules` and did an `npm install` again.  then did the import on the index.js and worked fine.  Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

This is webpack related...

Webpack needs to use loader to read and parse different import statements...

CSS loader https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader